# Power Set Definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I know that if x is an element of the set A, then {x} is a subset of A and that {x} is an element of the power set of A.

But, does it go the other way as well...? That is, if {x} is a subset of A, then x is an element of A?

I am working on a few power set proofs but always seem to get stuck unless I use this fact. It makes sense intuitively to me, but I can't give a rigorous proof of it.

The proof I was working on is:

> Prove that the Power Set of A is a subset of the Power set of B when A is a subset of B

Comment: In set theory the $\in$ relation is the basic one and the other are defined through it. Specifically, $A \subseteq B \text {  iff   } \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

Comment: Thus, from $\{ x \} \subseteq A$, we apply the above def to get : $\forall x ( x \in \{ x \} \to x \in A)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and in fact $\{x\} \subseteq A \iff x \in A$.

---

As for your problem, note that $A \subset B \iff a \in B \ \forall a \in A$.
So let $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ then $X \subseteq A$. Therefore, whenever $x \in X$, we also have $x \in A$ but $A \subseteq B$, so $x \in B$.

Consequently, whenever $x \in X$, we must have $x \in B$.

Can you finish the argument?

Answer (score 0):

hypothsesis: {x} is a subset of A.

Now let us suppose that x does not belong to A, in other words, let us suppose that the sentence " x belongs to A " false.

Since, as you know, the sentence : " x belongs to A" implies the sentence : {x} is a subset of A, our supposition " x does not belong to A " leads to the consequence : {x} is not a subset of A.

But that consequence contradicts our hypothesis.

So our initial supposition must be false : it is false that " x does not belong to A".

In other words ( using the logical law of double negation) : x belongs to A.

Conclusion : if {x} is a subset of A, then x belongs to A.

Answer (score 0):

If (X,t) be a topological space with given topology t is considered as discrete topology then total number of subfamily is called power of set.Power of set can be found. by 2ⁿ. If A ={1,2,3} then power of set is 2³=8. 8 subsets we find, which are ∅,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,3},{1,2,3].